# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined - Wrogrsin

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, undefined

I defined my variable as:

```
var Players = [{
    name: "personA",
    score: 50
  },
  {
    name: "personB",
    score: 50
  },
  {
    name: "personC",
    score: 50
  }
];
```

and the error is:

```
for (v=0;v<T;v++)
{
    show += "<br/>" + Players.score[v];
}
```

i have already defined T and show

Comment: Ok!! What is your question?

Comment: Your name is probably not in question?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify which `Player`. Change the code to use `Players[v].score`:

```
for (v = 0; v < T; v++) {
    show += "<br/>" + Players[v].score;
}
```

The `Players` is an array, not the `score`.

Answer (score 1):

`Players.score[v]`is undefined.

It should be `Players[v].score`.

You defined your `Players` variable as an array, so you have to loop over this array and not the `score` key.